# Why do I get an Inconsistent Accessibility error, "parameter type is less accessible than method"?

Tags: c#, accessibility, public

I have the following Class, `RoomMonitor`, set up as so:

```
class RoomMonitor {
    public RoomMonitor (Account acc) {
           // Init stuff
    }
}
```

And the `Account` class is set up as:

```
class Account {
    public Account (DataRow row) {
           // Init stuff
    }
}
```

This error shouldn't be happening then since both classes are public, right? And yet, I get the error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Hotel_Manager.Objects.Account' is less accessible than method 'Hotel_Manager.RoomMonitor.RoomMonitor

Comment: You show public *constructors* but are the classes themselves marked as `public`?

Comment: @JohnKoerner `Objects` *could* be a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown looks like the constructors for the two classes. The class declarations themselves should both be public. For example:

```
public class RoomMonitor
```

If they are not, you will get this error.

Comment: It is not important that `RoomMonitor` class is public. Either `Account` class should be made public, or the problematic constructor of `RoomMonitor` should be internal.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the message says; The parameter of type Account the public method is not public.

Make the type `Hotel_Manager.Objects.Account` `public` as well to resolve this.